# Linq - Except one list with items in another

Tags: c#, linq

I think my question is easy, but I'm a newbie in linq... So I'm having a hard time here

My system calls a service, called serviceTOP, that returns me a list of `itemTOP {Id, Name}`.

These ItemsTOP aren't in my system, but the user can choose which itemTOP to import to the system.

The imported ItemsTOP becomes an object `Item { Id, IdTOP, Name }`

So, when the system calls serviceTOP, before showing them to the user, I must filter the already imported items from the list.

Let's go to code:

```
IList<ItemsTOP> listTOP = new ServiceTOP().GetItemsTOP();

IList<Items> list = new WCFServiceClient().GetItems();

var filteredListTOP = listTOP.Select( i => i.Id ).Except( i => i.IdTOP );
```

This kind of works, but it returns a list of strings containing only the id.

I'd like to select both id and name of the TOP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change this:

```
listTOP.Select(i => i.Id )
       .Except( i => i.IdTOP );
```

To this:

```
listTOP.Select(i => new { ID = i.id, Name = i.Name} )
       .Except( i => i.IdTOP );
```