# looping through 2 lists to get the results

Tags: linq, list

I have two lists:

```
myObject object1 = new myObject(id = 1, title = "object1"};
myObject object2 = new myObject(id = 2, title = "object2"};
myObject object3 = new myObject(id = 3, title = "object3"};

//List 1
List<myObject> myObjectList = new List<myObject>{object1, object2, object3};

//List 2
List<int> idList = new List<int>{2, 3,5};
```

Now I need to get output as follows:

1. If a id is present in both the lists, I need to print "A",
2. if a id is present in `list1` only, then I need to print "B",
3. ...and if the id is present in `list2` only, I need to print "C"

Can I use linq to achieve this?

Comment: i tried to solve this prob using two foreach loops.but i was not able to get the 3rd case to run properly. as the inner loop never knew is an ID was not there in the outer loop.i dont know if the above statements made any sense...plz help

Comment: You need a separate step to get all unique IDs from both lists, in order for the rest of the logic you want to work.

Comment: can LINQ help me in this ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply use the inbuilt functions of `Except` and `Intersect`

1. List1.Intersect(List2) = "A"
2. List1.Except(List2) = "B"
3. List2.Except(List1) = "C"

There are plenty of resources online about how you could go about doing this, as one example (I didn't look into it too much), check out this link - [Linq - Except one list with items in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625689/linq-except-one-list-with-items-in-another)

Hope this does the trick...

Comment: i have implemented the following logic...

1. created a list of string that will hold all the unique ids in both the  lists.
2. then user that Intersect and Except methods to get three diffrent list for the 3 senarios.
3. then i looped through all the unique items and checked that in which catagory they fitted. 
   
Do suggest me if this is the correct way to solve this prob. if you have any other suggestion please let me know.

Comment: That seems just about right - Your only other option would be to create an object with 2 properties `id` and `category` and fill it in in roughly the same way.